# Changing saturation of a single color

Tags: colors

Is it possible to change saturation of a single color (r, g or b) if my monitor doesn't have such an option? Can't find it anywhere. Search engine doesn't give an answer because it thinks I'm asking something else.

Comment: Look up 'colour profiling' & 'display calibration', the precise details of which depend on many more criteria than you have given us.

Comment: What is the make and model of your monitor?

Comment: Ditto. Additionally, if it cannot be done in the monitor then maybe it can be done by software. What is your OS? video card? video driver? Anyway, you need to post more information ([edit] the question).

Comment: The trouble with trying to do this from the display's OSD is that there will be no rational curve applied, nor are you even going to be starting from a standard 120cd/m You could end up fixing it in the lights for it to be out in the darks.

Comment: Monitor software doens't provide an option like this. Windows 10. How is video card related to this?